# Missing ROLE_ANONYMOUS in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security

I have been using Spring Security 2.x for some time now, but recently I switched to 3.x. I always use my own implementation of `UserDetails` interface and authentication against DB.

Everything works fine (logging in, logging out, url filters, seeing username of authorized user, etc.).

The only thing left to do was to display "Please login" message when user is not authorized. I tried few approaches:

```
<sec:authorize access="not isAnonymous()">
or
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')">
etc.
```

None of them worked. Finally I added `<sec:authentication property="principal.authorities" />` to my home page output to debug what roles user really has. This is what I see:

- Logged user - `[ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN]`
- Unathorized user - `` <- empty String

It looks like I somehow lost the default `ROLE_ANONYMOUS` authority, which was always added by Spring, if I recall correctly. Was that recently dropped or something? Perhaps I have to take care of this anonymous access in some other manner?

Relevant part of security context:

```
<beans:beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- UNPROTECTED RESOURCES -->
    <http pattern="/" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/favicon.ico" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/home" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/login*" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>

    <!-- PROTECTED RESOURCES -->
    <http auto-config='true' use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/dashboard" authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=true"/>
        <logout logout-url="/logout"/>
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="userAccountsAuthenticationProvider" class="pl.xxx.utils.UserAccountsAuthenticationProvider" />

    <beans:bean id="saltSource" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.ReflectionSaltSource">
        <beans:property name="userPropertyToUse" value="salt" />
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userAccountsAuthenticationProvider">
            <password-encoder ref="standardPasswordEncoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anonymous Authentication can be configured in few different ways - do you use `<http auto-config="true">`, `<anonymous>` tag or define beans by yourself as custom filter? It'll be easier if you posted your security-context.xml.

Anyway, you want to display "Please login", so I assume you really wanted

```
<sec:authorize access="isAnonymous()">Please login</sec:authorize>
```

without "not" (by the way I can't find if "not" is a valid part of expression in this context).

Another way is to use `isAuthenticated()` instead, negate it in EL and see if it works in your case:

```
<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()" var="isAuthenticated" />
<c:if test="${not isAuthenticated}">
  <!-- do stuff -->
</c:if>
```

**EDIT:**

Change `security="none"` to `access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"` and move chosen patterns to intercept-url. It should enable Spring Security's Filter Chain and apply `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` on request:

```
<!-- UNPROTECTED RESOURCES -->
<http pattern="/favicon.ico" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>

<!-- PROTECTED RESOURCES -->
<http auto-config='true' use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/home" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/dashboard" authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=true"/>
    <logout logout-url="/logout"/>
</http>
```

assuming you want use `isAnonymous()` in `/`, `/home` and `/login*`.

My previous solution worked, because with `security="none"` checking for `isAuthenticated()` **always** yielded false, so negating it was like checking for not being loggged.

Comment: Added security context. As you can see I am using `auto-config` but not `<anonymous>` or custom filters. Also `<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">` works but your example with setting `isAuthenticated` variable does not. Strange.

Comment: My mistake - your solution with passing value of `isAuthenticated()` to variable and checking it in `if` statement works! But this does not answer my question quite yet - what happened to `ROLE_ANONYMOUS`?

Comment: In other words:
`<sec:authorize access="isAnonymous()" var="myVar" />
<c:out value="${myVar}"/>`
This snippet ALWAYS shows me: `false`.

Comment: Checked the config and found the problem (`security="none"` bypassed `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter`) - see my edit.

Comment: Did changing to `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` help?

Comment: Xaexess, thanks for the reply! I will check it out today in the evening and reward you with a correct answer if this is true. Based on what you say, I expect it to be solved, as indeed `security="none"` was something I used for the first time. I should probably focus on this right from the scratch :-)

Comment: Not quite. Since I am using `use-expressions="true"` in my config, adding `access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"` yields an exception saying that this property couldn't be evaluated by Spring.
Hoever, that is a viable alternative:
<intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll"/>

Then `isAuthenticated()` and `isAnonymous()` works as expected.

Thanks! I will accept your answer but please edit it and include this comment so that other people could see it right away without browsing through the comments.